# Install steam game does not give other library folders as option

Tags: steam

I want to install a new game but only the default library location is being offered.

I have two locations setup in the steam settings.

```
D:\Program Files(x86)\Steam\SteamApps (0 installed) - DEFAULT
U:\Games\SteamLibrary (8 installed)
```

I uninstalled another game (Transformers) that was on the U: drive and went to install it again. Only the default option was offered. I cannot remove the default folder as it is the default or the U: folder as it already has games installed.

U: drive has over 100gb free.
I am aware of the mklink method so dont want that as an answer.

I have also tried closing and opening steam and rebooting.

I have tried adding a new steam folder location as a test. That too does not show up as an install option. Only the default folder.

Comment: Is it by chance a Source game? I thought I heard Source games can only go into Default (due to sharing Source files)

Comment: The game is called "Just Cause" I dont know what a source game is or if it is. However, my example cites Transformers as a game i uninstalled from the U: drive and now cannot install back to the U drive.

Comment: I just tried installing Just Cause and it offers me all my set up locations as well as offers to create a new location. Have you tried re-installing Steam?

Comment: @BenBrocka Could you please say where you found that information? I'm having the same sort of trouble with a Source game and I would like to read more about what you said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Attempt 1 - Uninstalling and reinstalling.**

Once I reinstalled I had to re-add the library location after-which steam then automatically detected the existing games were  already installed. nothing was lost.

When I went to install my new game, the game location from my manage libraries was finally there.

**Update 2 - the workaround**

*The problem has returned. I don't know what triggers it. So the following is an easier workaround than reinstalling Steam.*

- Install the game to the undesired library location.
- Wait for downloading to be completed (may not be required, as it could continue downloading in the new location).
- Close steam.
- Move the files and folders from the install SteamApps folder to the other library folder.
- Start steam and it will detect where the games have been moved to.

This success of this can be verified by bringing up the properties of the game, clicking Local Files tab and clicking on "browse local files" to see the actual location path.

Comment: On computer reboot or steam restart, the problem has returned. So I am still investigating...

Comment: You may want to mark your question as answered?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I changed the default install folder. Once I changed the default folder I could choose any folder in the install menu.